# why third party package Autofac comes with two packages?

Tags: .net, autofac, nuget-package

sorry for this basic question, just want to ask why almost all third package comes with more than one packages on nuget? For example, Autofac comes as:

```
<PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="6.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.2.0" />
```

why not make everything into a single package e.g. `Autofac`? isn't it more concise and straightforward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One package is Autofac, the inversion of control container.

One package is the adapter that can convert Microsoft format registrations into Autofac registrations.

You can use Autofac without the adapter. Lots of people do, and this is how things work for non-.NET-core projects. Hence, it's two packages - you opt-in for the features you want.

It's the same reason you don't find all the classic ASP.NET, WCF, Moq, and other integration support in the core Autofac package.